# Swiperefresh under viewpager with fragments and recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I implemented  CoordinatorLayout->appbarlayout->toolbar,tablayout and viewpager.

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
             />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In viewpager I have a fragment for each tab, with Coordinatolayout->swiperefreshlayout->recyclerview.

Xml from a tab:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/postsList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/whitepaper2"
            />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is that the swiperefresh in fragments does not work with recyclerview 22.2.0, as it does with 21.0.0! But, with 21.0.0 the toolbar&fab do not auto hide/show.

```java
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'-----> 21.0.0
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Is there another method to control swiperefresh under viewpager->fragments->recyclerview?